# How to plot the effeciency of my cplex code?

Tags: cplex

I want to plot the efficiency/ convergence to the optimum solution of my cplex code in graphs as  i want to describe my code efficiency in some plotted graphs

Answer (score 0):

With OPL you can use the progress chart.

With docplex / python API you can have a look at the [progress listener](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/progress.ipynb) example

[image]